# How to manually set a cookie in JMeter that is set programmatically by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies, jmeter

I am testing a web application which has a following flow :

1. User logs in
2. On successful login, an access token is issued.
3. Every request after login has the access token to get a resource.

In my JMeter test plan, I added a cookie manager and I could extract this access token from the response header of the login request. I want to set this access token as a cookie the test plan.

I added this after extracting the access token in a BSF PostProcessor : *vars.put('COOKIE_access_token', actual_token);* and it is seen as a cookie variable in the debug sampler.

[image]

But the subsequent requests after login do not have this access token in their cookie data, and as a result are again redirected to login page.

How can I set this token as a cookie which will be used for all further requests?

Answer (score 6):

Defining variable does not add the cookie itself. You need to insert cookie into Cookie Manager to make this work, like:

1. Add a [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) as a child of the request which fails
2. Put the following code into the PreProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;

   sampler.getCookieManager().add(new Cookie("access_token", "actual_token", "domain", "path", true, Long.MAX_VALUE));
   ```

Replace `domain`, `path`, `true` (stands for "secure") and `Long.MAX_VALUE` (expires) with your own values.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for example of manipulating cookies programatically.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T. It worked. Although while inserting the cookie I had to give negative (-1) value as the expiry time. Any non negative value did not work. 
Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you god for this answer. HTTP Cookie Manager is a complete waste of time and so is JMeter for that matter, but at least this answer adds the ****ing cookie to my darn request.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;

sampler.getCookieManager().add(new Cookie("access_token", "actual_token", "domain", "path", true, Long.MAX_VALUE));
```

This code really worked. This helped me.
Who ever wants to pass missing cookie(session or any cookies) in request cookie data , instead of adding header manager please use the above code in bean shell pre processor.

Thank you  DMITRI T

Comment: the answer is not in readable format. please correct the formatting  of the answer using code and other needed blocks.